# Get "data" in Vue redirect router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redirect, vue-router

What I want to achieve is that when accessing `/self`, it should first check if `issignedin` is true and then get the value of `user.name` to redirect. Those variables are set in Vue's `data(){...` part.
Nevertheless, I wasn't able to figure out, how I could access the data since the Vue Instance is created *after* I create the routes:

```js
const routes = [
//...
  {
    path: "/self",
    redirect: (to) => {
      if (app.issignedin) { 
        return "/@" + user.name;
      } else {
        return "/login";
      }
    },
  },
];
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});

const app = new Vue({
  router: router,
  data() {
    return {
      issignedin: true,
      user: { name: "MoPaMo" },
//...
    };
  },
```

Neither `this` nor the name of the variable holding Vue (`app`) nor something like `this.$parent` works... :(

Help will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Try before enter. You basically need navigational gaurds in vue.js. check https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: But don't I have the same problem with Navigation Guards?

Comment: Why should it? You should revive your system flow. In order to access a particular url, first some data should be present. The vue will load on `/` and I don't understand why any user would directly type`/self` to land on your route before vue load

Comment: Imagine that it's deployed in example.com with a welcome home page and a button or link to go to example.com/self usually web portals work like that. And if you want user data then it usually comes from server api with an async call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue Router 3 provides [`router.app`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-app) to access the app instance that installs the router, and you could use that to access `app.issignedin`.

You could do:

```js
let router = null

const routes = [
  //...
  {
    path: "/self",
    redirect: (to) => {
      if (router.app.issignedin) { 
        return "/@" + user.name;
      } else {
        return "/login";
      }
    },
  },
];

router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});
```

Or if you prefer to keep `router` a `const`, use a regular function after the `router` declaration, which captures the `router` instance within:

```js
const routes = [
  //...
  {
    path: "/self",
    redirect: redirectIfNotSignedIn,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});

function redirectIfNotSignedIn() {
  if (router.app.issignedin) { 
    return "/@" + user.name;
  } else {
    return "/login";
  }
}
```